# JS: Multiple objects in an array stored in local storage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I've been trying to do this all day and just can't get it right. I've read many articles on various websites and tried many different approaches, but I am still getting issues of one kind or another.

Sorry if it's a little haphazard, I'm struggling to see my issue and so I'm struggling on what area to ask for help.

**Component aim:** Array stored on LS that holds objects, that hold information on shows
**Component issue:** Depending on the code I seem to either be overwritting a single object, cant log more than 2 objects (that then overwrite each other) or after storing 1 object fine the array starts messing up with more entries.

TLDR:

All I'm trying to do at this point is:

-push new object onto new showList array

-pull my objects from a showList array in LS (if exists), push into new showList

-stringify, then push my new combine array into LS

Below is the relative function.

```
function addNewShow(titleArg, typeArg, genreArg, watchedArg) {
  var showList = [];

  var show = {
    title: titleArg,
    type: typeArg,
    genre: genreArg,
    watched: watchedArg
  };
  showList.push(show);
  showList.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('showList')));
  console.log(showList);


  localStorage.setItem("showList", JSON.stringify(showList));
};
```

If you'd prefer to see the project you can see that here: https://codepen.io/11PH/pen/NONJBa?editors=1011

Any help much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are pushing entire array received from local storage into second position of local *showList* array, you should use array concatenation:

```
localStorage.removeItem('showList');

function addNewShow(titleArg, typeArg, genreArg, watchedArg) {
  var showList = [];

  var show = {
    title: titleArg,
    type: typeArg,
    genre: genreArg,
    watched: watchedArg
  };
  showList.push(show);
  showList = showList.concat(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('showList')||'[]'));
  console.log(showList);


  localStorage.setItem("showList", JSON.stringify(showList));
};

addNewShow(1,2,3,4);
addNewShow(1,2,3,5);
addNewShow(1,2,3,6);
addNewShow(1,2,3,7);
```

Little snippet showing why **(jsonString||"[]")** is important:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4];
console.log("array is:");
console.log("\t",  array ); 
console.log("concating null adds new null element to the array");
console.log("\t",  array.concat(null) ); 
console.log("concating empty array deosn't change anything");
console.log("\t",  array.concat([]) );
console.log("result of expresion (null||[]) is empty array not null");
console.log("\t", null||[]);
console.log("puting it all together, if we don't want to add null to the array then we can write   array.concat( null||[] )");
console.log("\t",  array.concat( null||[] ) ); 

console.log('additionaly JSON.parse(null) in null');
console.log("\t",  JSON.parse(null) );
```

Array.concat just works that way - MDN is great source of documentation and examples - [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for *concat*.

Comment: I had tried concatenating, must have messed it up somewhere. Could you explain a bit about the ' || '[]' " you wrote? I thought it was to create the array to store within but that's done further up with var showList = [];

Comment: _localStorage.getItem('showList')||'[]')_ is to get array when value of showList item in local storage is null. If it's null then we run _JSON.parse_ on string _"[]"_ - that return empty table and guarantees that parameter passed to showList.concat( _parameter_ ) is always the array.

Comment: Why would it ever be null though, before any entries have been made? Is it just a safety net?

Comment: It would be null before initialization on item in localStorage(run localStorage.getItem('asdjbsdfhbj') and check result), if i haven't change null to empty array concat would add null as last element to array. I'm adding snippet to answer to illustrate it, wait a moment.

Comment: This is all really helpful thank you, the example is great. A bit I still struggle to understand is why does concat add null? If I'm going round in circles I'll look into concat so more I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You should read `showList` from localStorage first, then push `show` onto that array.

```js
function addNewShow(titleArg, typeArg, genreArg, watchedArg) {
  // Get array from local storage, defaulting to empty array if it's not yet set
  var showList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('showList') || "[]");

  var show = {
    title: titleArg,
    type: typeArg,
    genre: genreArg,
    watched: watchedArg
  };
  showList.push(show);
  localStorage.setItem("showList", JSON.stringify(showList));
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks that seems like a clean fix thanks, I guess I had things in thew wrong order. This helps explain the ` || "[]" `a bit also. Is it implemented for the first entry? As there wouldn't be an array before any entries.

Comment: Right. When there's no LS item yet, `getItem` returns `null`, so we use `"[]"` as the default.

Answer (score 0):

first check for localstorage, then you can use  spread operator for iteration

```
  function addNewShow(titleArg, typeArg, genreArg, watchedArg) {
  var showList = [];

  var show = {
    title: titleArg,
    type: typeArg,
    genre: genreArg,
    watched: watchedArg
  };
  showList.push(show);
  var finalArr = localStorage.getItem('showList') != undefined ? [...showList, ...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('showList'))] : showList;
  localStorage.setItem("showList", JSON.stringify(finalArr));
};
```

Comment: Your function won't work when invoked for first time. It will set _showList_ to ""(string containing serialization of empty string) instead of array of length 1 with element from local variable _show_.