# How do I run a loop through JSON code to find only specific strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, loops, oauth-2.0

I am working with **Figma API** and I am parsing some JSON **(this is not my entire JSON FILE)**. A little context about the JSON file:

- None of these JSON objects are next to each other.
- All JSON objects fall in objects but they appear sequentially
- and their are an unlimited amount of `absoluteBoundingBox`
- and the `absoluteBoundingBox` could go by other names I'm not sure
  what names are or would be.

The issue I'm running into is:

- I need to loop through each `absoluteBoundingBox`
- give that `absoluteBoundingBox` a unique `id`
- and its own `x` `y` and `width` and `height` variables`
- store those in a new variables so that the variable containing the
  objects will need to be created every time a `absoluteBoundingBox` appears.

I know this is a big scope of work. But I need to know where to start.

## JSON

```
[{
  id: "6:3",
  absoluteBoundingBox: [{
    x: -406,
    y: -274,
    width: 437,
    height: 56
  }]
}],
[{
  id: "10:3",
  absoluteBoundingBox: [{
    x: -406,
    y: -201,
    width: 437,
    height: 56
  }]
}],
[{
  id: "10:4",
  absoluteBoundingBox: [{
    x: -406,
    y: -122,
    width: 437,
    height: 56
  }]
}],
[{
  id: "10:5",
  absoluteBoundingBox: [{
    x: -406,
    y: -28,
    width: 437,
    height: 56
  }]
}]
```

## JS

```
const frameJSON = {};
const getFrame =
  args.document["children"][0]["children"][0]["absoluteBoundingBox"];

var manyFrames = args.shift().filter(function(v) {
  return args.every(function(a) {
    return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
  });
});



var FrameID = {};
var textHeight = [];
var textWidth = [];
var textY = [];
var textX = [];
var FrameID = [];
var frameSize = getFrame.keys(getFrame).length;
frameJSON.getFrame = [];
for (b; b > frameJSON; b++) {
  if (b < getFrame.frameSize) {
    [x] = frameJSON.getFrame.push(getFrame[b].x);
    [y] = frameJSON.getFrame.push(getFrame[b].y);
    [width] = frameJSON.getFrame.push(getFrame[b].width);
    [height] = frameJSON.getFrame.push(getFrame[b].height);
    [id] = frameJSON.getFrame.push(getFrame[b].id);
  }
}
```

## what is being returned

\
right now I am returning these variables with in my FrameJSON OBJECT I would like to crate atleast 4 FrameJSON objects.

[image: right now I am returning these variables with in my FrameJSON OBJECT]

I tried:

```
const getFrame =
  args.document["children"][0]["children"][0]["absoluteBoundingBox"];
  const listOfFrames = []

  //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52672037/js-multiple-objects-in-an-array-stored-in-local-storage

  getFrame.push('absoluteBoundingBox');
  getFrame.push('id');
  showList.concat(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listOfFrames')))
  localStorage.setItem("listOfFrames", JSON.stringify(listOfFrames));
```

in order to get a list of frames but the code isn't running like I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the ( ) to [ ] in the raw JSON string and parse it as an array of 4 objects. Then you can parse the JSON object directly in a browser's developer console.

```
var json=" ... paste your [] wrapped JSON string here";
//edit: if you have no control over the source string, do a replacement before parsing:
json=json.replace(/\(/g,'[').replace(/\)/g,']');

var objs=eval('('+json+')');
for (k in objs){
  var obj=objs[k];
  //do whatever you want with the obj here
}
```

To further illustrate the difference in formatting, try this in a browser console:

```
objs=({a:'123',b:'xx'},{a:'222',b:'yy'});
```

This will give an object of one element, as the ( ) is not proper format.

But this:

```
objs=[{a:'123',b:'xx'},{a:'222',b:'yy'}];
```

gives both objects. However, when a JSON string is transported, it is a string, so the following doesn't give a proper collection, but a string:

```
json="[{a:'123',b:'xx'},{a:'222',b:'yy'}]";
```

A nice trick to convert a string representation of a JSON object is to eval it like this:

```
json2="([{a:'123',b:'xx'},{a:'222',b:'yy'}])";
```

note the added brackets!

```
objs=eval(json2); //this gives you a proper array
```

BUT, your original string has ( ) instead of [ ], so the string replacement is necessary.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think I know what your trying to say. Could you add a bit more to your answer so I can understand what you are trying to do. I also can't change the JSON  file because the JSON is being pulled from an API. @IanHeister

Comment: I have added two lines to address this issue.

Comment: what does a replacement before parsing do to my JSON do you have an example? @Ian Heisler

Comment: explanation added to the answer. hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what issue you are solving? Are you just saying that I'm not able to work with the JSON because it is not formatted properly because that wasn't the issue stated above. I'm working with the JSON that Figma gives me.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm getting at. The JSON file's content is not properly encoding a collection of objects. The fact that the file is returned by a software project doesn't necessarily mean it is correct, at least not in your context.

Comment: it seems like your Reg exes aren't working 
`TypeError: Cannot find function replace in object [object Object].
    at fuction3(Copy of Copy of make type:607)` @Ian Heisler

Comment: glad to hear that!

Comment: handler my JASON objects are highly nested and according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750127/regex-for-parsing-single-key-values-out-of-json-in-javascript he sugests not using regexes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202539/discussion-between-zachary-blumstein-and-ian-heisler).